# Python XML Parsing Children and grand children attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, xpath, xml-parsing

I have been trying this on and off for the last two weeks and going over python's documents for XML parsing. I still can figure out if it's an Xpath thing or not. If anyone can provide some help I would greatly appreciate it.

My XML file has many children and I am using the root.findall() to get the attribute for myAccessPoints and then three children below it I have an element with several attributes I want to extract. However, so far, I'm only able to do this with 2 for loops.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET



def apData():

    tree = ET.parse("project.xml")

    root = tree.getroot()
    for topLevels in root.findall("./myAccessPoints//*[@id]"):
        myApId = topLevels.get('id')
        print("AP:%s" % myApId)
        print()
        #return myApId

    for radio in root.findall("./accessPoints/accessPoint/radio/*"):
        rChannel = radio.get('primaryNumber')
        rMac = radio.get('mac')
        rSsid = radio.get('primaryNumber')
        print(rChannel, rMac, rSsid)
        #return rChannel, rMac, rSsid
```

Here is an example of the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
  <maps>
    <map id="0" name="floorplan" pixelsPerMeter="47.808212118953044" type="fspl"/>
  </maps>
  <accessPoints>
    <accessPoint id="0" userDefinedPosition="false">
      <radio type="measured">
        <accessPointMeasurement mac="a0:63:91:21:c4:f8" ssid="Eggs" primaryNumber="7" primaryFrequencyMhz="2442" centerNumber="7" bandwidthMhz="20" security="WPA2" informationElements="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">
          <technologies>
            <technology band="802.11g"/>
            <technology band="802.11b"/>
            <technology band="802.11n"/>
          </technologies>
        </accessPointMeasurement>
      </radio>
    </accessPoint>
    <accessPoint id="1" userDefinedPosition="false">
```

Eventually I would take the access point element attributes like so -->

accessPoint id

accessPointMeasurement mac, ssid, primaryNumber

technology band

technology band

technology band

Some accessPoint elements have 2 sets of radios so I would have to get accessPointMeasurement attributes twice.

I imagine I'll have to create a class and within the class I'd have to make lists or dictionaries within themselves.

I'm not asking anyone to do anything for me other than to understand how I can get each access point and it's attributes in one for loop (If it's even possible).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expanded your XML to include more `accessPoints` and `radios` and used the lxml library to get access to its xpath features. Nested loops.

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse('temp.xml')
accessPoints = tree.xpath('.//accessPoint')

for accessPoint in accessPoints:
    print ('accessPoint id:', accessPoint.attrib['id'])
    radios = accessPoint.xpath('radio')
    for radio in radios:
        accessPointMeasurement = radio.xpath('accessPointMeasurement')
        print ('\taccessPointMeasurement: ', accessPointMeasurement[0].attrib)
        technologies = radio.xpath('.//technology')
        for technology in technologies:
            print ('\t\ttechnology: ', technology.attrib)
```

Results are these:

```
accessPoint id: 0
    accessPointMeasurement:  {'security': 'WPA2', 'informationElements': '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', 'bandwidthMhz': '20', 'centerNumber': '7', 'mac': 'a0:63:91:21:c4:f8', 'ssid': 'Eggs', 'primaryFrequencyMhz': '2442', 'primaryNumber': '7'}
        technology:  {'band': '802.11g'}
        technology:  {'band': '802.11b'}
        technology:  {'band': '802.11n'}
accessPoint id: 2
    accessPointMeasurement:  {'security': 'WPA2', 'informationElements': '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', 'bandwidthMhz': '20', 'centerNumber': '7', 'mac': 'a0:63:91:21:c4:f8', 'ssid': 'Eggs', 'primaryFrequencyMhz': '2442', 'primaryNumber': '7'}
        technology:  {'band': '802.11g'}
        technology:  {'band': '802.11b'}
        technology:  {'band': '802.11n'}
    accessPointMeasurement:  {'security': 'WPA2', 'informationElements': '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', 'bandwidthMhz': '20', 'centerNumber': '7', 'mac': 'a0:63:91:21:c4:f8', 'ssid': 'Eggs', 'primaryFrequencyMhz': '2442', 'primaryNumber': '7'}
        technology:  {'band': '802.11g'}
        technology:  {'band': '802.11b'}
        technology:  {'band': '802.11n'}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Bill. It looks like I need to learn a little more about Xpaths.

Comment: Judging from one or two of the xpath answers I've given in the past couple of days, I can learn a lot more as well! I think it's a tad tricky if one comes from a mainly procedural background. There's probably a better way than what I've offered here. And incidentally, if you value an answer on SO you can up-vote it once you have enough reputation. People like that.

Comment: I'm not often on stackoverflow and I don't know if you are interested, but I have a github account with this project up.

I'll warn you ahead of time.... I am a beginner so my code probably won't be readable and this may just be a waste of your time.


[My GitHub](https://github.com/HH0718/Ekahau_Parse)


SO won't let me up vote but I marked this post as answered.

 Thanks Bill.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know you could do that. Thanks. Will look at what you're doing and see if it's something I would be able to understand.